# Apache SOLR: Giving extra results with Standard Query Parser on Logical AND

Tags: solr, query-parser

I ran into this strange issue, while using Logical AND for my Standard Query Parser. I am searching for terms "steve" and "austin" in the query. I am getting 8 matches, out of which only 2 contain both the terms, and rest of them only contain steve. FYI, I tried the same query using edismax parser, and it returns 2 hits exactly, as expected.

Query(Standard Parser): `http://localhost/select?q=all_name:(steve AND austin)&fl=*_name&wt=xml&hl=true&hl.fl=*&hl.simple.pre=<em>&hl.simple.post=</em>&debug=true&indent=true
I am using phonetics on the terms, so terms in highlight do not exactly match steve. I am particularly surprise to see the last result, which lists nothing inside <em> tags.`

I tried highlighting, to check, why 8 results are being selected. Here is highlighting output:

```
    <lst name="highlighting">
    <lst name="1852237_1_1">
    <arr name="first_name"><str><em>Steve</em></str></arr>
    <arr name="last_name"><str><em>Austin</em></str></arr>
    <arr name="all_name"><str><em>Steve</em></str></arr>
    </lst>
    <lst name="1844776_1_1">
    <arr name="all_name"><str><em>Steve</em> <em>Austin</em> Productions, LLC</str></arr>
    <arr name="full_name"><str><em>Steve</em> <em>Austin</em> Productions, LLC</str></arr>
    </lst>
    <lst name="3021779_1_1">
    <arr name="first_name"><str><em>STEVEN</em> JAY</str></arr>
    <arr name="all_name"><str><em>STEVEN</em> JAY</str></arr>
    </lst>
    ..........
    <lst name="1871189_1_1">
    <arr name="all_name"><str>; Anderson, David; Anderson, Don; Jordon, Gary T; Oliver, James Theodore; Oliver, Jim</str></arr>
    <arr name="full_name"><str>; Anderson, David; Anderson, Don; Jordon, Gary T; Oliver, James Theodore; Oliver, Jim</str></arr></lst>
    </lst>
```

Comment: Do you have the output from the top of the XML document showing which query arguments are in effect?

Comment: Could you please also show the schema section related to the `all_name` field type.